# Is the Makkachin tissue box based on Yuzuru Hanyu's tissue box?

Tags: yuri-on-ice

In Yuri!!! on ICE, Viktor has a tissue box in the shape of his dog Makkachin, which he uses when coaching Yuuri. Is there any indication whether this is based on Yuzuru Hanyu's Pooh Bear tissue box? Have any statements been made by the creators about that?
[image: Yuzuru Hanyu's Tissue Box][image: Makkachin Tissue Box]

Comment: My guess is there hasn't been (or I'd have heard something by now, since I've been follow the series somewhat), but I'm not sure of it.

Comment: Other than [Japanese fans' speculation](https://togetter.com/li/1059693), I couldn't find any official reference from the author. But given that she used many real-life figure skating related references before, it wouldn't be surprising if it was.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the Makkachin tissue box was inspired off of Johnny Weir's old Russian cartoon themed tissue box.

Many elements from the show were inspired by him as well from the tissue box, to the flower crowns Viktor wore, Viktor's custom gold blades, and right down to Viktor's feathered costume. All of those things were known and inspired by Johnny. The feathered costume came from his first Olympics as a swan skating to Swan Lake. Every time he won a comp. Johnny got a flower crown, and Johnny's favorite color was gold so he got custom made gold blades.

All of these were inspirations from Johnny Weir.

Comment: Possible references: [An Interview with Johnny Weir: His Thoughts on ‘Yuri on Ice’](https://thegeekiary.com/johnny-weir-watched-yuri-ice/40241), [Fandom Wikia](https://yurionice.fandom.com/wiki/Victor_Nikiforov#Trivia)?